# What does this symbol mean: ∧?

Tags: delphi, math, formula

I need to calculate this equation using Delphi programming language

```
z = (Rot(y ∧ n1 , K2) ∧ K1 ) ⊕ n2
```

Where:
K1, K2, n1, n2, y are 96-bits binary values

I just want to know what does this symbol means "∧", and how to us it in Delphi?

Comment: @utility, it's not asking what the Delphi operator is, it's asking what the _mathematical_ operation is, and how to do that in Delphi. That's two very different questions.

Comment: What is the context? Where did you find the equation? The reason I ask is that these operators can mean anything. If we know what the equation is used for then we can narrow it down. The equation didn't materialise out of thin air. If you know where it came from you can look a few pages each way in the text to find the definitions of terms.

Comment: bitwise XOR (⊕), bitwise AND
(^), bitwise OR (v
), addition 2m
 and left rotate Rot(x,y)  -  taken from a document about RFID validation

Comment: What version of Delphi will you be using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be bitwise AND.

The ⊕ could be [exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) XOR in Delphi.

The tricky bit might be the ROT operation which rotates the bits of a variable. There is no ROT operation but there is shl  and shr for left and right shift. See [Delphi Expressions](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/expressions_xml.html)

To make things even harder you don't have a native 96 bit datatype. LongInt is 4 bytes = 32 bit. You will need to use an array if you need to represent the fill 96 bit.